# Are questions regarding the performance of a game off topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently have had trouble with performance of a game (loading in etc). Would providing information about my system, as well as screenshots/footage of the issue be considered off topic?

If so, what Exchange would the question be more suited for?

The question title would be along the lines of "How can I reduce my load in time for [game]?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should be on-topic. As you've said, providing all the information you can is vital here. There are only a two caveats I can think of.

- Tech support for modded Minecraft is explicitly off-topic. Other modded games are still allowed but you'll get a much better response asking about the unmodded game or a specific mod.
- Trying to run a game when you don't meet the system requirements is off-topic. The answer in this case is to upgrade your system.